# Pygame spritecollide giving me iterable error

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I am using pygame to create a Brick Breaker game. I have gotten everything else to work except the collisions. I tried to use collide_rect but it didn't work, but it did not give me error messages. I tried to use spritecollide, but it gives me the error message Ball object is not iterable. My goal is to detect the blocks, remove it, and increase the score. Sorry, my code is a little messy. 
Here is my code (The collision detection is near the bottom):

```
import pygame
import paddle
import ball
import block
import time
import random
import math
screenW, screenH = 1280, 720

backroundColor = [0,0,0]

offset = 30
PaddleW = 200
PaddleH = 25
PaddleX = screenW / 2 - PaddleW / 2
PaddleY = screenH - PaddleH - offset

n = 10
blockW = screenW / n #128 per block
blockH = blockW /4 + 10
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Brick Breaker")
Display = pygame.display.set_mode((screenW, screenH))
Display.fill(backroundColor)

player = paddle.Paddle(PaddleX, PaddleY, PaddleW, PaddleH)

ballSize = 12
ballX = PaddleX
ballY = PaddleY-20
ballSpeed = -4
ballMoveY = ballSpeed
ballMoveX = ballSpeed
balls = pygame.sprite.Group()
balls = ball.Ball(ballX, ballY, ballSize)
#ballDraw = ball.Ball.draw(Display)

lives = 3
score = 0
shiftX = 0
shiftY = 0

#blocks init
'''blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
blocks = []'''

#block1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
block1 = block.Block(10,60,blockW,blockH)

counter = 0
def displayText(text, color, posX, posY, size):
    str(text)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('impact', size)
    textWrite = font.render(text, True, color)
    Display.blit(textWrite, (posX, posY))
def waitForKey():
    wait = True
    while wait:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                wait = False


'''m=3
for y in range (4): #Spawn blocks
    for i in range (0, int(screenW), int(blockW)):
        blocks.append(block.Block(i+2, blockH*(y+2), blockW-4, blockH-4))'''
block1.draw(Display)
#blocks.draw = (14,14,14,14)

FPSClock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 144

GameOver = False
Display.fill([130,140,230])
displayText('Brick Breaker', [200,230,100], 450,100, 80)
displayText('Use the mouse to move the paddle and bounce the ball. Try to break the bricks and not die.', [220,10,10], 120, 300,30)
displayText('Press space to begin', [0,0,0],520,510, 30)
pygame.display.flip()
waitForKey()
while not GameOver:
    counter += 1/FPS
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            if GameOver == False:
                GameOver = True
    mouseX = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    Display.fill(backroundColor)
    player.draw(Display)
    player.move(mouseX)

    balls.move(ballX, ballY) #pygame.draw.circle(Display, [0, 120, 120], [int(ballX), int(ballY)], ballSize)
    balls.draw(Display)

    '''
    for x in range(len(blocks)):
        blocks[x].draw(Display)
    '''
    #Draw blocks
    block1.draw(Display)

    if ballX <= 0:
        ballMoveX = -ballSpeed
        pygame.mixer.music.load("GungaGinga.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
        #shiftX = random.randint(-2,2)
        #shiftY = -shiftX
    elif ballX >= screenW:
        ballMoveX = ballSpeed
        pygame.mixer.music.load("GungaGinga.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
        #shiftX = random.randint(-2, 2)
        #shiftY = -shiftX
    if ballY <= 0:
        ballMoveY = -ballSpeed
        pygame.mixer.music.load("GungaGinga.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
        #shiftY = random.randint(-2, 2)
        #shiftX = -shiftY
    elif ballY >= screenH:

        pygame.mixer.music.load("OOF.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
        ballMoveY = ballSpeed
        lives -= 1
        ballX = PaddleX
        ballY = PaddleY - 20
        balls.move(ballX, ballY)
        #shiftX = 0
        #shiftY = 0
        time.sleep(1)

    if ballY <= PaddleY + PaddleW and ballY +ballSize >= PaddleY:
        if (ballX >= mouseX or ballX <= mouseX) and (ballX + ballSize <= mouseX + PaddleW/2 and ballX + ballSize >= mouseX - PaddleW/2): # or ballX + ballSize >= mouseX - PaddleW/2
            ballMoveY = -ballMoveY#ballSpeed
            pygame.mixer.music.load("GungaGinga.mp3")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
            pygame.mixer.music.load("OOF.mp3")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
    ballX += ballMoveX
    ballX = ballX +shiftX
    ballY += ballMoveY
    ballY = ballY + shiftY

    displayText('Lives: %s'%lives, [90,190,90], 20, 10, 40)
    displayText('Time: %.1f' %counter, [20,190,90], 1100, 10, 40)
    displayText('Score: %s' % score, [90, 190, 90], 570, 10, 40)
    if counter == 5:
        ballSpeed -= 1

#Collision Test
    #if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(balls, blocks):
        #blocks.kill(blocks)
    #hitBlock = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(blocks, player)
    '''    def hit(self):
        hit_block = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(blocks, self.balls, False, True)
        if hit_block:
            return True
        else:
            return False'''
    #is_a_collision = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(blocks, balls)
    '''
    if self.hit():
        print("collision")
        score += 10
        blocks.kill(blocks)
        '''
    #collision
    #hit_block = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(balls, block1, False, True)
    #hit_block()
    #pygame.Surface.get_rect(block1)
    #Current colliderect not working
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(block1, balls):
        score += 10
        #block1.kill()
        print("collision")

    #Spritecollide not working -  gives error message

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(block1, balls,False):
        #block1.kill()
        score += 10



    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSClock.tick(FPS)
    if (lives <= 0):
        #You died
        Display.fill([130, 140, 230])
        displayText('You Lost', [200, 230, 100], 500, 100, 80)
        displayText('Thanks for trying',[250, 10, 10], 540, 300, 35)
        displayText('Press space to exit', [0, 0, 0], 540, 510, 30)
        pygame.display.flip()
        waitForKey()
        GameOver = True
    #balls.hit()
    '''
    if balls.collide():
        print("collide")
        score += 10
        '''
pygame.quit()
```

Here is a sample of my classes:

```
import pygame

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, posx, posy, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(posx, posy, width, height)
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
    def draw (self, Display):
        pygame.draw.rect(Display, [6,130,183], [self.posx, self.posy, self.width, self.height])
```

I am using PyCharm
Please let me know what to do.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: I haven't read all of your code but this immediate reassignment looks suspicious: `balls = pygame.sprite.Group() \ balls = ball.Ball(ballX, ballY, ballSize)`.  Also, if you are using PyCharm then I would address all of the grey squiggly lines :-).

Comment: @FiddleStix setting balls = ball.Ball(ballX,ballY,ballSize) makes it easier to call in the code. I also tried without calling 'balls' and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the condition

> ```py
> if (ballX >= mouseX or ballX <= mouseX) and (ballX + ballSize <= mouseX + PaddleW/2 and ballX + ballSize >= mouseX - PaddleW/2):
> ```

The result of the 1st condition (`(ballX >= mouseX or ballX <= mouseX)`) is always `True` and the 2nd condition is screwed up.

If you have a range for `x1` to `x1+w1` and a 2nd range from `x2` to `x2+w2`, then the 2 ranges are overlapping if

```py
x1 <= x2+w and x2 <= x1+w1
```

So the collisiton test has to be:

```py
if ballY <= PaddleY + PaddleH and PaddleY <= ballY + ballSize:
    if ballX <= mouseX + PaddleW/2 and mouseX - PaddleW/2 <= ballX + ballSize:
        ballMoveY = -ballMoveY
        score += 10
```

---

Anyway I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and the method [`.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect). e.g:

```py
ball_rect   = pygame.Rect(ballX, ballY, ballSize, ballSize)
paddle_rect = pygame.Rect(mouseX-PaddleW/2, PaddleY, PaddleW, PaddleH)
if ball_rect.colliderect(paddle_rect):
    ballMoveY = -ballMoveY
    score += 10
```

---

Since your objects are [`Sprites`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), I recommend to to keep the `.rect` attribute up to date.e.g:

```py
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.posx, self.posy = self.rect.topleft
```

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def move(self, x):
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.posx = self.rect.left
```

Now you can use the `.rect` attributes of the objects for the collision test:

```py
if ball.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
    ballMoveY = -ballMoveY
    score += 10
```

Since both objects are sprites it is rcommend tor use [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect):

```py
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(ball, player):
    ballMoveY = -ballMoveY
    score += 10
```

---

Note, a collision of a `Sprite` object and a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) or event 2 `Group`s can be found by [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) respectively [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). e.g.:

```py
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
blocks.add(block.Block(10,block1Y,blockW, blockH, blockColor))
```

```py
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, blocks, False):
    ballMoveY = -ballMoveY
    score += 10
```

```py
for block in blocks:
    block.draw(Display)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried to check collisions with the blocks (block1) usings collide_rect but that doesn't work. For the paddle, I had coded the paddle by using coordinates.

Comment: I get no error messages, but when I run the code, nothing happens. If there is a collision, it’s supposed to increase the score, but it doesn’t. I would ideally like to spritecollied, but when I try to use that it say “‘ball’ object is not iterable”.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to get the block collisions working by using collide_rect. Spritecollide still gives me the iterable error, but that is ok. I am trying to use more blocks, but the second one doesn't detect collisions. I copied the same definition and collide_rect function and changed it from block1 to block3. block1 still works, but block3 doesn't.

Comment: @MiPlayer123 For multiple blocks in a Group you've to use  `spritecollide` for a single Sprite you've to use `collide_rect`

Comment: I am using if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(balls,block1,True):
                                             print("collisions") but it gives me the error 'Block' object has no attribute 'sprites' and I am not sure why

Comment: @MiPlayer123 Is `block1` a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) object? Probably not.

Comment: It is a sprite group and it is set up like this: block1 = pygame.sprite.Group
block1 = block.Block(10,block1Y,blockW, blockH, blockColor)

Comment: @MiPlayer123 No it's not! After the instruction `block1 = block.Block(10,block1Y,blockW, blockH, blockColor)` the variable `block1` is a Block object and a Block object is of derived from Sprite. You've to add the sprite to the Group: `block1 = pygame.sprite.Group()` `block1.add(block.Block(10,block1Y,blockW, blockH, blockColor))`. I've added new suggestions to the answer (last section)